# what does % mean in a makefile rule

Tags: c++, makefile

So i know that the pattern rule `%.o : %.cpp` is for making any *file.o* from a *file.cpp*
But what I want is different. Let's say I want to make a *file1.o* from *folder1/file1.cpp*, and a *file2.o* from *folder2/file2.cpp*.
What i thought about doing was :

```
file1=folder1/file1
file2=folder2/file2

%.o: $(%).cpp
```

But that doesn't work. Do anyone have an idea on how to do that apart from manually doing :

```
file1=folder1/file1
file2=folder2/file2

file1.o: $(file1).cpp

file2.o: $(file2).cpp
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)? Did you read the [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) ? Did you consider generating some `include`d part of your `Makefile`?

Comment: It's a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html).

Comment: If your source files are all uniquely named (they should be) then you could just use a [`vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#The-vpath-Directive).

Comment: If you have *many* such files, a [canned recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `%` in GNU Make is documented in the [seciton on Defining and Redefining Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules).

If the target name is `foo.o`, then `%` is `foo`. I don't want to go into any more depth on the meaning of `%` here.

In your case, the dependencies between the object files and the source files cannot be expressed easily using a single simple rule. I would advise making the rules explicit instead of using a pattern-based rule.

```
file1.o : folder1/file1.cpp
file2.o : folder2/file2.cpp
```

You'll need to add the commands to build those targets too.

```
file1.o : folder1/file1.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

file2.o : folder2/file2.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

Comment: You should make clear that it's not enough to list targets and prerequisites like this, you also have to include the recipe for each rule.